# Python: consecutive lines between matches similar to awk

Tags: python, regex, string, awk, regex-lookarounds

#### Given:

- A multiline string `string` (already read from a file `file`)
- Two patterns `pattern1` and `pattern2` which will match a substring of exactly one line in `string` each. These lines will be called line1 and line2.

The patterns are regex-patterns, but I can change their format if that makes it easier.

#### Searched

I am looking for a way to get all the lines between line1 and line2 in python (we can safely assume that line1 is before line2).

Of course this could be done in a for loop with a flag set by `pattern1` and a break when `pattern2` matches. I am looking for a more *compact* solution here, though. This is a trivial oneliner in `awk`:

```
awk '/pattern1/,/pattern2/' file
```

#### Example:

file:

```
aaa aa a
bbb bb b
ccc cc c
ddd dd d
eee ee e
fff ff f
```

pattern1: `b bb`

pattern2: `d dd`

Desired outcome:

```
bbb bb b
ccc cc c
ddd dd d
```

Comment: I would like to do it in python. (corrected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `awk` the `/start/, /end/` range regex prints the entire line that the `/start/`is found in up to and including the entire line where the `/end/` pattern is found. It is a useful construct and has been copied by Perl, sed, Ruby and others.

To do a range operator in Python, write a class that keeps track of the state of the previous call to the `start` operator until the `end` operator. We can use a regex (as `awk` does) or this can be trivially modified to anything returning a `True` or `False` status for a line of data.

Given your example file, you can do:

```
import re

class FlipFlop: 
    ''' Class to imitate the bahavior of /start/, /end/ flip flop in awk '''
    def __init__(self, start_pattern, end_pattern):
        self.patterns = start_pattern, end_pattern
        self.state = False
    def __call__(self, st):
        ms=[e.search(st) for e in self.patterns]
        if all(m for m in ms):
            self.state = False
            return True
        rtr=True if self.state else False
        if ms[self.state]:
            self.state = not self.state
        return self.state or rtr

with open('/tmp/file') as f:
    ff=FlipFlop(re.compile('b bb'), re.compile('d dd'))
    print ''.join(line if ff(line) else "" for line in f)
```

Prints:

```
bbb bb b
ccc cc c
ddd dd d
```

That retains a line-by-line file read with the flexibility of `/start/,/end/` regex seen in other languages. Of course, you can do the same approach for a multiline string (assumed be named `s`):

```
''.join(line+"\n" if ff(line) else "" for line in s.splitlines())
```

Idiomatically, in awk, you can get the same result as a flipflop using a flag:

```
$ awk '/b bb/{flag=1} flag{print $0} /d dd/{flag=0}' file
```

You can replicate that in Python as well (with more words):

```
flag=False    
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r'b bb', line):
            flag=True
        if flag:
            print(line.rstrip())
        if re.search(r'd dd', line):
            flag=False
```

Which can also be used with in memory string.

Or, you can use a multi-line regex:

```
with open('/tmp/file') as f:
    print ''.join(re.findall(r'^.*b bb[\s\S]*d dd.*$', f.read(), re.M))
```

[Demo and explanation](https://www.regex101.com/r/d3OnNk/1)

But that requires reading the entire file into memory. Since you state the string *has* been read into memory, that is probably easiest in this case:

```
''.join(re.findall(r'^.*b bb[\s\S]*d dd.*$', s, re.M))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `regex`:

```
>>> print(a)

aaa aa a
bbb bb b
ccc cc c
ddd dd d
eee ee e
fff ff f
```

The expected result:

```
>>> print(re.search('^.*bb b$\n((:?.+\n)+)^.*dd d$',a, re.M).group())
bbb bb b
ccc cc c
ddd dd d
```

Or just the enclosed text:

```
>>> print(re.search('^.*bb b$\n((:?.+\n)+)^.*dd d$',a, re.M).group(1))
ccc cc c
```

Comment: The regex `^.+bb b$\n((:?.+\n)+)^.+dd d$` would require at lease one character before `bb b` and one character before `dd d` because of the `.+` vs `.*`

Answer (score 1):

Use the re.DOTALL to match on anything including newlines. Then plug in the beginning pattern and end pattern:

```
re.search( '[\w ]*b bb.*?d dd[ \w]*', string, re.DOTALL).group(0)
```

Note: (1) `string` here is the file or string you wish to search through. (2) You'll need to `import re`.  If you really want to be concise, perhaps to the point of fault, you can combine reading the file and extracting the pattern:

```
re.search( '[\w ]*b bb.*?d dd[ \w]*', open('file').read(), re.DOTALL).group(0)
```

Comment: Does not capture the line before `pattern1` or the remainder of the line after `pattern2`

Comment: ah, OP changed what he wanted. Edited to accommodate. Thanks.

Comment: That *still* does not include the start of the line with `b bb` in it or the end of the line with `d dd` in it. The entire lines need to be printed from beginning to end.

Comment: Now it only matches lines 2-n-1. Instead of `\n` use `re.M` and then add `^` and `$` to your pattern.

Comment: @dawg, I think matching the data properly, no? And, using re.M means I'd have to include the newlines in the pattern.

Comment: Try `re.search( '\n(.*?aa a.*?d dd.*?)\n', open('file').read(), re.DOTALL).group(1)` No match because there is not a `\n` before the first line. Same problem with the last line.

Comment: @dawg Ah, literal edge cases. Ok, amended.